# Failed to brew install pyqt on Mac OS Sierra via command line tool

Tags: macos, pyqt

I tried to`brew install pyqt`.
However, it ends up with

```
make: *** [sub-plugins-make_default-ordered] Error 2

READ THIS: https://git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
 qt: migrate to boneyard https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/7019
 Transition formulae to Qt 5 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/1705
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyqt` depends on Qt4, which is End Of Life and not supported anymore. Therefore, the Homebrew `pyqt` package has been removed from the main repository and now lives in the [boneyard](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-boneyard).

You could try and install it from there:

```
brew install homebrew/boneyard/pyqt
```

However, perhaps it's better to take a look at `pyqt5`.